# Ruby: each loop to constant length

Tags: ruby

In ruby, my each loop looks like this:

```
(1..3).each do |i|
```

I would like to be able to define a constant:

```
NUMBER_OF_BOXES = 3
```

Then loop to this constant.  In pseudo it would look like this:

```
(1..NUMBER_OF_BOXES).each do |i|
```

How do I do this in Ruby?

Comment: This `(1..NUMBER_OF_BOXES)` and  `(1..3)` is same.

Comment: Your question is unclear. The code you have works. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by others, your "pseudocode" does already what you want.
Also quite nice and ruby-ish: `1.upto(NUMBER_OF_BOXES) do |i| ... end` (see [ruby docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Integer.html#method-i-upto))

Answer (score 2):

```
NUMBER_OF_BOXES.times do |i|
  ... i + 1 ...
end
```

Comment: Nice - that is very neat

Comment: Sorry about non mentioning that.

Answer (score 1):

> In pseudo it would look like this:
>
> `(1..NUMBER_OF_BOXES).each do |i|`

In Ruby code it would look like this:

```
(1..NUMBER_OF_BOXES).each do |i|
```

Comment: Note that you're comparing apples and oranges. The linked thread talks about `times.map`, not just `times` or `each`